# Why does delete operator does not work on an Object created with Object.create() method

Tags: javascript

Why does `delete` operator not working on object's created using Object.create() method.

```
var Dog = {
  name: 'tommy',
  height: '4'
};

var newDog = Object.create(Dog);

delete newDog.name

console.log(newDog.name) // still returns "tommy"
```

Comment: *`The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object.`*

Comment: you can use `Object.assign` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method is used to create a new object which extends the existing object which you have passed, in your case it's `Dog` object.

When you delete the `name` property in your `newDog` object, it deletes perfectly, but the inherited `name` property from the `Dog` object is still there. so you should delete that too.

```
var Dog = {
  name: 'tommy',
  height: '4'
};

var newDog = Object.create(Dog);

delete newDog.name; // It deletes the property in the newDog, but still the Dog property contains the name property so when you console.log(newDog.name) it prints Dog.name property.

console.log(newDog.name)

delete Dog.name;

console.log(newDog.name); // now it's deleted
```

Answer (score 2):

`delete` indeed removes a property from an object. But if the object inherits the property you're trying to delete, rather than having its own property with that name, `delete` won't work. You're essentially trying to remove something that doesn't exist. The property you're trying to delete is a property of the object's prototype (or elsewhere in the object's prototype chain), not the object that inherits it.

You can check if an object's property is its own using `yourObject.hasOwnProperty()`. If `hasOwnProperty()` returns `true`, then you can use `delete` to remove that property.

Otherwise, you'd have to remove the property from the "parent" object.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the property from newDog, it does delete the property. You can console the object and see. However, when you call again newDog.name, internally the prototype (of newDog) is set to Dog. So since newDog.name doesn't exists, it goes up the prototypical chain and it finds that property on the Dog object and it prints that value.